# Jquery inputpicker plugin calling mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I 'm using this jquery plugin([Link](http://www.inputpicker.com/www/)) and I 'm stuck in below code where I 'm not sure how to call the mvc controller and fill dropdown with data.

```
<input class="form-control" id="test" value="" />
<script>
$('#test').inputpicker({
    url: './example-json.php',
    fields:['id','name','hasc'],
    fieldText:'name',
    fieldValue:'id',
    pagination: true,
    pageMode: '',
    pageField: 'p',
    pageLimitField: 'per_page',
    limit: 5,
    pageCurrent: 1,
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to set the `data` property as shown in the examples you linked to. Pass a model to the view that is `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` contains properties `id`, `name` and `hasc` and then convert it to a javascript array using `data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.YourCollectionProperty)),`

Comment: Or use the example shown in the _Remote data_ section that uses ajax to call a server method that returns a `JsonResult` of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps which can help you in implementation. First in your controller create an action method which will retrieve data for the imputpicker. See the below sample action method.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetContacts(string q, int limit = 5, int p = 1, int per_page = 5)
    {
        var result = new List<ContactModel>();
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 1, Name = "Name1", Address = "Address1", Email = "email1@email.com", Phone = "1234567899" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", Address = "Address2", Email = "email2@email.com", Phone = "1234545439" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 3, Name = "Name3", Address = "Address3", Email = "email3@email.com", Phone = "1234543349" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 4, Name = "Name4", Address = "Address4", Email = "email4@email.com", Phone = "1253567899" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 5, Name = "Name5", Address = "Address5", Email = "email5@email.com", Phone = "1234566755" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 11, Name = "Name11", Address = "Address11", Email = "email11@email.com", Phone = "1234567899" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 12, Name = "Name12", Address = "Address12", Email = "email12@email.com", Phone = "1234545439" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 13, Name = "Name13", Address = "Address13", Email = "email13@email.com", Phone = "1234543349" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 14, Name = "Name14", Address = "Address14", Email = "email14@email.com", Phone = "1253567899" });
        result.Add(new ContactModel { Id = 15, Name = "Name15", Address = "Address15", Email = "email15@email.com", Phone = "1234566755" });

        return Json(new { msg = "", count = result.Count, data = result.Skip((p - 1) * per_page).Take(per_page) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Sample ContactModel is below

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view put the following code

```
<input class="form-control" id="test" value="Text 2" />
<script>
    $('#test').inputpicker({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetContacts", "Home")',
        fields: ['Id', 'Name', 'Email'],
        fieldText: 'Name',
        fieldValue: 'Id',
        filterOpen: true,
        pagination: true,
        pageMode: '',
        pageField: 'p',
        pageLimitField: 'per_page',
        limit: 5,
        pageCurrent: 1,
    });
}
```

Your inputpicker should work now.

Comment: Thanks alot Nitesh, you rock.